# React functional component : can we setState on form load event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

react component with hooks:

**Requirement:** when page load, data populates, from backend, into dropdowns and multi-select tables(tables with checkboxes). On the Submit button click, I need to use this consolidates object (for the default values selected) to make another REST call.

**NOTE:** No change handler called for any of these ui components.

Issue:

1. The state is not set at all and if I try to it goes to an infinite loop. as it keeps rendering the page again and again.
2. if I try to set state and use it, being an async call, the state is not available at that time.

**Suggestion needed:** is there a way to setState of the default selected values on form load event.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
const changeRequests = useSelector(state => 
  state.oncallRequest.changeRequests
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) {
    dispatch(fetchRequests(), [dispatch])
      .then(response => setData(setDefaultState(response.data)));
  }
}, [changeRequests.fulfilled, dispatch]);
```

And I got the below error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.async call.
```

**Action Class:**

```
export const fetchRequests = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: LIST_PENDING});

    listChangeRequests().then(data => {
        dispatch({type: LIST_FULFILLED, changeRequests: data})
    }).catch(err => {
        dispatch({type: LIST_FAILED, changeRequests: {error: err.message}})
    });
};

**Service Class**
export const listChangeRequests = () => axiosInstance.get(`/getData`).then(res => {
    return res.data;
});

SOLUTION:
I used 2 use Effect: one for fetching data from backend and another for setting state.

**but getting the following exception**
1) **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setDefaultState'. Either include it or remove the dependency array**
2) 'data' is assigned a value but never used 

Please advise on the warnings...

    useEffect(() => {
  if (!changeRequests.fulfilled) {
    dispatch(fetchRequests(), [dispatch])
  }
}, [changeRequests.fulfilled, dispatch]);

-------------
useEffect(() => {
        if (changeRequests.data) {
            setData(setDefaultState(changeRequests.data));
        }
    }, [changeRequests.data]);
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. There is not enough information here to help.

Comment: OFC. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt.

Comment: Actually it's more of a question:
If iI setState of components in one of the handlers, it works but here I cannot touch any of the handlers at all(all are disabled), how can I setState.

Comment: @DaveNewton@DrewReese Updated the code

Answer (score 3):

Likely, you don't know [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), at the initial mounting of your component the `useEffect` can call an API and then change the state by using `useState`. like below:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const FormComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    // call an API and in the success or failure fill the data by using setData function
    // It could be like below
    ApiCall()
      .then(response => setData(response))
      .catch(err => setError(err))
  }, []);

  ~~~

};
```

**UPDATE**

This part is added after your code adding. actually your `dispatch` function doesn't return `Promise` event doesn't return anything. so the usage of `then` in your code is not acceptable and the JavaScript interpreter should return an Error. I guess you should focus on your `dispatch` function.

Comment: Yaa, looking to return something that can be used here... Thanks

Comment: updated answer.solved issue but gettng wasnings**React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setDefaultState'. Either include it or remove the dependency array**

Comment: Dear @Roy, do you reach to your answer?

Comment: 1) **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setDefaultState'. Either include it or remove the dependency array**
2) 'data' is assigned a value but never use.

Comment: any advise please

Answer (score -1):

You need to use useEffect and useState Hooks for this.

```
  useEffect(() => {

     // write any code that will execute at first time

  }, []);  <-- [] is the empty dependency.
```

In the below example, **LoadUser()** function is called in **useEffect** that will be getting data from api. After successful call, response data is set into the state using **setPosts (useState Hook)**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function ExamplePost() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    LoadUser();
  }, []);

  function LoadUser() {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
        cancelToken: this.signal.token
      });
      response
        .then((response) => {
          setPosts(response);
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError(error);
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ExamplePost;
```